# Excel data from colum to row

Tags: vba, excel, row, multiple-columns

I have data like in the picture below:

[image]

I need to (with a macro) arrange the data so that every row with a number after ELEVATION\AZIMUTH be in the first row, like in picture:

[image]

I have a lot of rows like this data. Maybe any one can help?

Comment: This can be done in vba easily , if you know how to write macro then write a loop to check column A for `Elevation` then again a nested loop to move the data in the fist row as you need. let us know if you stuck somewhere ou will help you.

Comment: im not good at writing macro by myself, i'm able to make some correction to work macro for my situation :) so if you can give me some macro code basic i will figure it out :) @Shirikant

Comment: how many records do you have like `Elevation` and is the data fixed to 9 cells /

Comment: i'm using merge macro to collect data from separate txt files. it is 
recurrent data with different number. One section is (A1:I20). I need to get all numbers in to one row. So from one section i have to get three rows. i can have sections like this a lot about 200 or more.  And yea it is fixed to 9 cells. @Shrikant

Comment: have posted an untested code give it a try . you can also add this code below the merge macro to get what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not tested. you can give it a try. the below can be written in diff way as well.

```
  Sub test1()
        Dim LastRow, DataCount, temp  As Double
        i = 1
        LastRow = 1

        Do While LastRow <> 0
            Range("A" & i).Select
            If ActiveCell.Value = "ELEVATION\AZIMUTH" Then
                'Cut all three row and paste
                DataCount = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range(i & ":" & i))
                Range("A" & ActiveCell.Row + 1, "I" & ActiveCell.Row + 1).Cut ActiveCell.Offset(0, DataCount)
                Range("A" & ActiveCell.Row + 2, "I" & ActiveCell.Row + 2).Cut ActiveCell.Offset(0, DataCount * 2)
                Range("A" & ActiveCell.Row + 3, "I" & ActiveCell.Row + 3).Cut ActiveCell.Offset(0, DataCount * 3)
            Else
                LastRow = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A" & i, "A" & i + 10))
            End If
            i = i + 1
        Loop

    End Sub
```

Comment: you can you offset if the data is not fixed to column `I` . like this `Range("A" & ActiveCell.Row + 1, activecell.offset(1,datacount)`

Comment: it' not working and i don't know what is not correct. its just thinking (Spinning wheel) i don't know how to say correct. i'm pressing Esc to stop :) then i can see "Select" or object "Range" failed then press degug it;s show to this : Range("A" & i).Select . @Shrikant

Comment: You are AMAZING!! Thank YOU! :) @Shrikant

Comment: one more question to you, now i need to cut and paste all values by ELEVATION\AZIMUTH to one row up. i believe i need to make changes here:  LastRow = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A" & i, "A" & i + 10)) ? @Shrikant

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151592/discussion-between-shrikant-and-skirmante-valentaite).

Comment: is there are any way to work this part of code faster? I have about 4000 rows ore more.. and it takes like eternity..

Comment: Well , you can speed this up by adding `Application.Screenupdating = false`

Answer (score 2):

This can also be done without the use of macros. 
I am assuming your last column where data is there is column I and the row number is 11. You want to fill all cells in row 11 after column I, i.e. J11,K11.... with values right below I11

You could do this, paste in J11
J11=INDEX($I$11:$I$1000,COLUMN(B1),1)
Drag the formula across the row and you should get your desired output

Comment: it is taking only one column value to row, i need all columns value in one row :) but thanks, i is good formula i believe i can use it one day :) @user8441712

Comment: You mean to say all values from say, B12 to I50 should completely be there? This could be done by = INDEX($B$12:$I$1000,ROUNDDOWN((COLUMN(B1)-2)/7,0)+1,MOD(COLUMN(B1)-2,7)+1). I assume your data has 7 columns. So the row number in the index gets appended by 1 after every 7 cells, and column index iterates from 1 to 7 and back as you move from cell to cell